# Why would a UK resident need both passport and BRP while travelling within the UK?

Tags: uk, air-travel, passports, uk-residents

I have a business trip from Bristol to Edinburgh and the travel agent who booked the flights advised me to have my passport and BRP (biometric residence permit) with me.

Since I have never needed my passport while travelling within the UK before, I got confused. This is a domestic flight and there is no passport check. In case needed, my BRP should be sufficient to show my legal status in the UK.

Is there any reason to carry both documents?

Comment: Does the BRP have your photo on it?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yes.

Comment: Did you ask the travel agent why they recommend you carry both?

Comment: It might be an airline requirement (have a valid ID issued by your own government) rather than a required by UK law one.

Comment: @Traveller They said just "by experience".

Comment: You can find out the reality by carrying both but only volunteering your BRP. See who, if anyone, asks for the passport.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some airlines, especially low cost carriers like Ryanair and easyjet, have passenger documentation requirements which far exceed those required by law. Ryanair in particular is especially infamous for this. Your travel agent will have been aware of this and would advise you to carry both your passport and BRP to ensure that you did not have any trouble with airline requirements which exceed the requirements of law.

Further, it may happen that you unexpectedly need to travel outside the UK for some unforeseen reason. If you have your passport with you, (and already have any necessary visas) you will be able to do this without returning home to pick it up.

Comment: The last bit of advice is often overlooked but definitely useful.  Unexpected trips abroad do indeed arise when one is away from home.

Comment: I've lost count of the people who were away from home without their passport that have come to this very site asking for travel advice with respect to their forgotten passport and some urgent situation. Simply having it with you would solve many suuch problems.